# cuDNNの初期化が失敗する

Tags: ubuntu, tensorflow, anaconda, keras, cuda

**問題点**
Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS、Anacondaで
keras-gpu、tensorflow-gpuを使いたいのですが、
cuDNNの初期化が失敗したとのエラーが出ます。

以下の環境下のspyderで[lenet.py](https://github.com/oreilly-japan/deep-learning-with-keras-ja/tree/master/ch03)を実行すると、このようなエラーが出ます。

```
UnknownError:  Failed to get convolution algorithm. This is probably because cuDNN failed to initialize, so try looking to see if a warning log message was printed above.
     [[node sequential/conv2d/Conv2D (defined at /home/xxx/ダウンロード/deep-learning-with-keras-ja-master/ch03/lenet.py:78) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_842]

Function call stack:
train_function
```

**環境**
1.osにインストールしたnvidiaドライバー（GPU：GeForce GTX 1660 Ti）

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 450.57       Driver Version: 450.57       CUDA Version: 11.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 166...  Off  | 00000000:08:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 41%   37C    P8    17W / 120W |   1280MiB /  5941MiB |      2%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1418      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                 18MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1465      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell               48MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1662      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                338MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1796      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell              242MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2313      G   ...AAAAAAAAA= --shared-files      560MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      6429      G   ...kawa/anaconda3/bin/python        2MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     17279      G   ...AAAAAAAAA= --shared-files       62MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A     17758      G   gnome-control-center                1MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

2.Anaconda(version 1.7.2)

3.仮想環境 tf-gpu をAnaconda Navigatorで作成し、
　tensorflow-gpu(2.2.0)、keras-gpu(2.4.3)、scikit-learn、pillow　をインストール

4.spyderをインストールし、起動。前項のプログラムを実行し、前述の通りエラー発生。

**試したこと**
[同じようなエラー](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/24828)が出た人がtensorflow-gpuを1.8.0にダウングレードすればよいと
アドバイスされていましたが、navigatorでダウングレードしようとすると以下のように拒否されました。

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with your CUDA driver:

  - feature:/linux-64::__cuda==11.0=0

Your installed CUDA driver is: 11.0
```

正直cudaについては詳しくないため、ドライバーをどう入れ直したらよいかわかりません。

pythonのバージョンも変えてみたりしましたが、結果は同じでした。

どうかご教授よろしくお願いいたします。